# What is the proper way to call class functions using Symfony's router and http-foundation components?

Tags: php, symfony

I've recently plugged Symfony's Routing and HttpFoundation components into my legacy app, and I'm slowly starting to convert all of my code over.

Everything's working surprisingly well so far, but I think I'm heading down a rabbit hole with the way I've structured my controllers and the way the router calls them. Here is some of the code located in my front controller:

```
// look up the controller and action defined in routes.yml
$parameter = $router->match($request->getPathInfo());

// call the action and get the output
$output = call_user_func('MyCompany\\Controller\\' . $parameter['_controller']);

// send the output in the response and so forth
// ....
```

So, the call_user_func line would actually call something like `MyCompany\Controller\GeneralController::indexAction`, which ultimately returns the html output, which is sent in the response.

Because of the way I have everything set up, I have to use statements like `return self::display('filename.tpl');`. This seems wrong to me.
Is there a better way to call these controller actions?

Comment: There is a controller resolver: http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolverInterface.html.  But I don't understand your question.  Why and where do you have to use statements like self::display to call a controller action?  Perhaps an example?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use [ControllerResolver](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.html). Or you might want to use HttpKernel more directly, which does the resolution for you.

If you use the ControllerResolver, it will create a "callable", and also fetch the arguments you can do `$response = call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments);`

There are a lot of other benefits to using the HttpKernel or AppKernel, which provide a lot more scaffolding.

Answer (score 1):

What you're having problems with, is actually dependency injection.`self::display` probably renders some template for you using some global variables (objects), what you instead need to do is something like `$this->renderer->render('filename.tpl')`. The easy way for you to do this without declaring Service Containers and etc. and hooking them to your router, is to provide some common arguments to all you controllers, i.e:`call_user_func('MyCompany\\Controller\\' . $parameter['_controller']);` becomes `call_user_func_array('MyCompany\\Controller\\' . $parameter['_controller'], ['array', 'of', 'common', 'dependencies']);`
or you could create a [Service Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) (Service Container in symfony terms) and pass that to all your controllers, and let them fetch their own dependencies.